# How to get function parameters except the first one?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

The following is my present implementation:

```
struct Dual {
    float v;
    std::valarray<float> d;

    Dual(float v, std::valarray<float> d): v(v), d(d) {}
    Dual(float v, float d = 0.f): v(v), d({d}) {}
};

Dual d0{1.f};              // OK.
Dual d1{1.f, 1.f};         // OK.
// Dual d2{1.f, 1.f, 1.f}; // Error. I want this.
Dual d2{1.f, {1.f, 1.f}};  // OK.    I don't want this.
```

Is it possible to use only one constructor?

So that `Dual d2{1.f, 1.f, 1.f};` is also OK.

Maybe like this (cannot compile):

```
struct Dual {
    float v;
    std::valarray<float> d;

    Dual(float v, float d...): v(v), d({d...}) {}
};

Dual d0{1.f};
Dual d1{1.f, 1.f};
Dual d2{1.f, 1.f, 1.f}; // I want this.
```

Should I use variadic template or `std::initilizer_list<>`?

And How to use?

Comment: Do you want all 4 versions to work with a single constructor, or are the first 3 versions enough?

Comment: The first three. I will clarify in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a constructor that takes a variadic number of arguments, like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
Dual(float v, Ts ...ts) : v(v), d({ts...}) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/tYzngp).

With c++20, you could simplify this to:

```
Dual(float v, std::floating_point auto ...ts) : v(v), d({ts...}) {}
```

This has the advantage over the previous version, that the constructor will only accept floating point values. (Even though the previous version will *warn* about narrowing conversions).

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nps-NV).

Comment: If demonstrating C++20, I think it would be beneficial to constrain the auto parameter to only floats using concepts.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work with C++20:

```
class Dual {
    float v;
    std::valarray<float> d;
public:
    Dual(float f, std::floating_point auto... f2)
    : v {f}, d{static_cast<float>(f2)...}  {}
};

int main() {
    Dual f1 {1.5};
    Dual f2 {1.5, 2.5};
    Dual f3 {1.5, 2.5, 3.5};
    // Dual f4 {1.5, 2.5, "3.5"}; // won't compile, type mismatch
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to the already existing answers, you can use a `std::initializer_list` (C++11). Unfortunately `valarray` has no constructor taking two iterators, which makes the code rather unwieldy:

```
#include <valarray>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Dual {
    float v;
    std::valarray<float> d;
    Dual(std::initializer_list<float> in) : v(*in.begin()),
        d(in.size() < 2 ? std::valarray<float>() : 
                          std::valarray<float>(&(*(in.begin()+1)),in.size()-1))
    {}
};


int main() {

    Dual d0{1.f};              // OK.
    Dual d1{1.f, 1.f};         // OK.
    Dual d2{1.f, 1.f, 1.f};    // OK.
}
```